# Tensorflow keeps showing requirement violation regarding "-ensorflow-gpu" on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow

I was trying to upgrade my previously installed tensorflow-gpu to a newer version, and when I do so, after checking a few requirements without any error, it says `-ensorflow-gpu 1.8.0 has requirement tensorboard<1.9.0, >=1.8.0, but you'll have tensorboard 1.12.2 which is incompatible`, followed by normal installation `Installing collected packages: tensorboard, tensorflow-gpu`.

With tensorflow installed, the following error message shows up when I attempted to run a program which makes use of tensorflow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\cli.py", line 88, in execute_script
    script = self.import_script()
  File "C:\...\lib\cli.py", line 34, in import_script
    module = import_module(mod)
  File "C:\...\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\...\scripts\gui.py", line 10, in <module>
    from lib.gui import (CliOptions, CommandNotebook, ConsoleOut, Session, DisplayNotebook,
  File "C:\...\lib\gui\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib.gui.display import DisplayNotebook
  File "C:\...\lib\gui\display.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .display_analysis import Analysis
  File "C:\...\lib\gui\display_analysis.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .stats import Calculations, Session
  File "C:\...\lib\gui\stats.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'`
```

It seems that the problem is caused by that little typo there saying `-ensorflow-gpu`, but I can't seem to find where that comes from.

Comment: you can try reinstalling packages

Comment: @Rifat Alptekin Çetin I've tried unintalling and reinstalling with different versions of tensorflow-gpu and the same thing still happens. Rebooting doesn't work as well.

Comment: can you add full error code to question?

Comment: @Rifat Alptekin Çetin I've added the error message as the result of running a program making use of tensorflow. The error occurs at installation stage is one line only.

Comment: you can try adding C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\ to PYTHONPATH. but something is not normal about your python installation.

Comment: @Rifat Alptekin Çetin Tried reinstalling python and now it works like a charm. Thx for the help mate.